# Custom Comparer in LINQ query to sort strings/numerics

Tags: c#, linq

I've written a custom comparer that sorts strings and numeric. This all works fine.

However I'm rewriting my whole BLL to use LINQ where possible as I do like the syntax. Now i'm stumbling onto using my custom comparer. As LINQ syntax (query based) will not allow to use custom comparers Im now using method based LINQ.

But in order to make it to work, I need to do an intermediate ToList(), which again works fine, but looks somewhat weird to me?

```
        var areas = cc.Areas.Where(a => a.ProjectId == ProjectId).ToList()
                            .OrderBy(a => a.UnitNumber, new Common.Comparers.StringNumericComparer());
```

Now i'm unsure if this has to do with the SQL query to be executed first and then the results sorted in my C# code side, but this is beyond my knowledge.
Does ToList() force the first part of the linq query to be executed on the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes your understanding is correct. Until the .ToList() it is an IQueryable. On ToList() a database query is fired and the results are fetched in memory and then a sort occurs on the List.

Your comparer cannot execute before this since it does not translate to an SQL query.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any performance issue related? I don't see any other option to achieve this. Could i rewrite this to query based syntax?

Comment: @Martin: There is definitely a performance issue. It brings the entire list to memory on ToList and in IQueryable it executes at the database as a query and brings back only the filtered results. Why do you need to create such a comparer?

Comment: But there is no other way to achieve this? The other side is that there won't be more than 10 rows really based on the first filter.

Comment: @Martin 10 records is in insignificant in this case.

Comment: The comparer sorts integers first in front of strings and sorts accordingly. When doing this query based, I suppose I'll end up having two queries, first one to query the DB the other one to sort the results.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `.ToList()` forces your `Areas` to be loaded and the sorting occurs in memory.